# Attempt to load JVM failed on native side

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, dd4t

We are working in a DD4T project using TFS as source control,
today when I opened the solution I had this error message : [image: JVM issue]

My colleague had this one yesterday, he restarted his computer and it fixed the issue, I tried to do the same but it wasn't working.

FYI I work with a 32bit workstation and he works with a 64bit workstation (both on windows 7) the website is hosted on IIS, do you have any idea of the origin of the issue ?

**Edit** : it looks like the issue is localized on IIS: the Visual Studio Development Server works fine with the solution.

**Edit2** : stacktrace :

> [JuggerNETFrameworkException: Attempt to load JVM failed on native side]
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load(Boolean bAcceptPreloaded) +287
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load() +41
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +111
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +49
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1082
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +54
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +50
>      Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) +202
>      Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Query..ctor() +49
>      Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query..ctor() +23
>      DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String Url) +230
>      DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) +780
>      DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String PageId) +124
>      DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.Page(String pageId) +71
>      *******.Web.UI.DD4T.PageController.Page(String pageId) in C:\Projects\Web\Sites\Dev\Client********.Web.UI.DD4T\PageController.cs:15
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +110
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +205
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod_callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      Castle.Proxies.Invocations.AsyncControllerActionInvoker_EndInvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +54
>      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +91
>      Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed() +13
>      Glimpse.Mvc.AlternateType.EndInvokeActionMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +57
>      Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +84
>      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +132
>      Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +182
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +237
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +237
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +126
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8968077
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: Maybe your colleague fixed it by checking in the 'wrong' dll's? (See Q's answer). So it works for him, but not for you...

Answer (score 13):

If you work on a 32-bit workstation, you need to use the 32-bit Tridion DLLs. The DD4T DLLs themselves are hybrid, they should be okay.
You can find the 32-bit versions of the Tridion content delivery DLLs on the Tridion installation CD.

Comment: In fact I already have DLL, I'm not sure they are 32-bit dll, do you know a easy way to detect it ?

Comment: The typical offenders are the Juggnernet runtimes - xmogrt.dll and netrtsn.dll - xmogrt.dll shows in the Details tab of the properties something like "Codemesh runtime for x86" or "amd64"

Answer (score 13):

firstly yes its 32 vs 64 bit dll/Jar issue, but in my case i was using correct 64 bit dlls/Jar, but in the app pool mistakenly "Enable 32 bit Applications" was set to true. After setting it to false resolved my issue.

Comment: Exactly right, the app pool and the DLLs have to match!

Comment: Also make sure that your .NET web app projects are set to build to Any CPU rather than x86 or x64 (project properties->Build->Platform Target) - it took me ages to troubleshoot this once, because I was using 32 bit locally but someone changed the project properties to build specifically for 64 bit.

Answer (score 7):

We've had exactly the same issue my colleague wrote this article to help explain the resolution:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tridion-content-delivery-deployment-errors-unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-and-system-badimageformatexception

Others tips are:

Ensure you have a valid content delivery licence.
Ensure your configuration xml files are referencing this file correctly - and they are valid XML.

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure you have correct version of Java installed. I recently had the same error and found out that my workstation did not have the 64 bit version of Java installed while the application was running on 64 bit.

Answer (score 5):

"Java failed to load on native side" is a very high level generic error. It just says the JNI bridge between C# and Java could not be established.

The reasons could be numerous. I once had it, and this was the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238273/http-deployer-throws-attempt-to-load-jvm-failed-on-native-side

Answer (score 4):

Whenever we had this issue (which was just now) it was do to the application pool identity running the deployer not having read and execute access to the Java install directory. You should also check the other things identified above. Hope that helps.