# Can 32 bit and 64 bit Tridion web application be mixed on one machine?

Tags: java

Mixing up 32 bit and 64 bit DLLs and Java JREs can lead to [issues](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/attempt-to-load-jvm-failed-on-native-side). I am investigating one and I wonder if we can have an IIS website in 64 bit (Tridion DLLs and JRE) and Visual Studio with IIS Express in 32 bit on the same machine?

And how does the web application find the right JRE?

Answer (score 3):

I hope I have understood it correctly - you can have two website with 32 bit dlls and 64 bit on the same machine. For this you can have respective JREs and DLL in the bin folder of the corresponding application i.e. - 32-bit website will have bin folder and in it a lib folder of all 32-bit Tridion JAR files and similarly for 64-bit application.

Moreover, you need to mark the following attribute in IIS Manager accordingly for the website:

In the Application Pool of the website, choose `Advanced Setting` and mark the highlighted attribute accordingly:
For 32-Bit application, this attribute need to be set to `True`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That should be possible. You have to make sure of three things:

1. Both the 64 as well as the 32 bit JRE need to be installed. You can check whether this is the case by looking into both the C:\Program Files\java as well as the C:\Program Files (x86)\java directories.
2. It might also be necessary to point each server to the right JVM. You can do this by adding a **jvm.xml** file next to your Tridion ContentDelivery DLLs. [Check this page](http://codemesh.com/products/juggernet/doc/runtime_config.html#explicit) for the exact settings. You will probably need to set the **JvmPath** option explicitly. This is necesary because you can't use the Windows registry nor the **JAVA_HOME** variable to get different JVMs for each server.
3. Ensure that  the proper bit version for the Tridion DLLs are present in both the 32 -and 64 bit servers.

Comment: I did 1) and 3) already. 2) is new to me, I will try it. Thanks