# DD4T: Attempt to load JVM failed on native side

Tags: 2011, dd4t

I am using Tridion 2011 with DD4T on a 64 bit environment.
I have hosted the CM on Server 1, CD on Server 2 and DD4T app on Server 3 with CM and Broker DB on Server 4. Whenever, I am trying to hit any URL (ensured the corresponding page is published to broker), I am getting below error:

```
Attempt to load JVM failed on native side
```

(No Error in any other log file or Windows Event Logs)

I have referred the other question with same error [HERE](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/attempt-to-load-jvm-failed-on-native-side) on Stack Exchange as well as elsewhere but of no success yet for me.

Till now I have tried following to resolve but to no success:

- Ensured the 64 bit CD DLLs and JARs are in use
- The 32-Bit application setting in the app pool is set to false
- The License file is correct and is referenced correctly
- Server Re-start
- Java Version - Both 32 and 64 bit version are fine (1.6.0.25)

Anything else, that you may suggest to help me resolve the issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was occurring due to the complex infrastructure - There was a service which in turn is calling another service hosted on another server and is using Tridion CD to interact with Tridion Broker. On this server the JRE was not installed properly. Re-installing proper JRE resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This issue is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238273/http-deployer-throws-attempt-to-load-jvm-failed-on-native-side. 
It could be one of two things:

- mismatch between 32 and 64 bit versions (you say you are using the 64-bit jar files but do you have a 64 bit JDK installed?)
- you are using too much heap memory (you can check this by creating a registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Tridion\Content Delivery\General\jvmarg1 with a low enough value, say -Xmx512M